# Robust Gaussian Fit

Tags: python, numpy, modeling, gaussian

I have tried to find some literature on robust gaussian fits, all I could find was good old EM gaussian mixtures.

The question is : given a mixture of gaussians, find the dominant one around a given point.

The problem with gaussian mixtures is that you need to know how many components you have beforehand. If you don't, there are algos that will run for a range of components and choose the one with the least BIC or AIC. For data with high absolute kurtosis, you can get two (or more) components with relatively equal means but different standard deviations. You can start merging the results, but hyperparameters get in the way and it becomes a mess.

So I tried my own approach by tweaking the EM algorithm a little bit, I have one hyperparameter (bw for bandwidth) (mu is mean and std is standard deviation):

Start with a mu and a reasonable std.

- Expectation : find the points in [mu-bw.std,mu+bw.std]
- Maximization : recalc the mu and std for those points. correct the std by dividing by the std of a trimmed standard normal on [-bw,bw].
- continue until convergence,
- the weight of the local dominant gaussian is the share of points in [mu-bw.std,mu+bw.std] (E-step) divided by the integral of a standard
  normal on [-bw,bw].

Here you can find a notebook

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kFSD1JVPoLFkWjydNj_7tQ91Z6BJDZRD?usp=sharing

I'm obviously weighing the points by a rectangular function. I was thinking of weighing by the gaussian itself (self-weighted). The mean wouldn't need correcting, but the weight and the std would. The weight is corrected by multiplying by (2sqrt(pi)) and the std by sqrt(2).

The pros of the self-weighted are that there is no need for a hyperparameter, it's faster in terms of loops, and has less bias on highly overlapped components. The con is that it will always converge to the global dominant gaussian whatever the starting point.

The pros of the rectangular-weighted are that it will converge on a local dominant, given a small enough bw (compared to the overlapping of components), although a small bw will have larger standard error on the parameters.

Edit : by this time, I have tried different mixtures and the self_weighted fails to converge. The correcting coefficients are wrong and I'm looking for help.

Comment: You've thought about this more than I have, but I did something like this with scipy.optimize.curve_fit, have you considered that? I remember being surprised there wasn't a more robust out-of-the-box solution for what seems like a common problem.

Comment: I think that curve fit is good if you have equidistant xi and frequency fi. Then you can fit a curve to (xi,fi). But here, I only have x_i, and in order to transform them into a (xi,fi) situation, I have to use some kernel density estimation (KDE). Which I did in a previous version, but there were too many artifices (bandwidth of kernel), and the function to minimize (weighted dist between the gaussian curve and the KDE) was not that obvious and would diverge to any trivial solution if the starting point (mu and sigma) was not close to the solution. I don't know how curve fit manages outliers.

Comment: Right, that's what i did, histogrammed the data and fit the curve. Like you said it occasionally failed to converge in the presence of noise and outliers